# FLUTTER FIRST RUN: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to perform my first `run` of a *test app* on flutter via **`Genymotion`**, but I get nothing except this message in console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Motorola Moto X in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.0/gradle-3.5.0.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Also (it may be helpful, I think), under the `build menu`, I don't find some practical sub-menus; such as `build`, `clean`, or ...

**What could be the problem?**

*any help is **really** appreciated!*

---

*Since @TaufikNurRahmanda needed the response of* `flutter doctor` *and* `flutter clean` *commands as more details, I am adding them as an edit;*

**flutter doctor:**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586], locale en-US)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
      instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**flutter clean:**

```
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.
```

---

Also the response of `flutter doctor --android-licenses` may be useful (although I have `Android SDK Build-tools 29.0.3` installed):

```
A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run: C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update
```

And when I run the suggested command above (`sdkmanager --update`), I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class '-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\\..-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
```

Comment: have you tried `flutter clean` and redo the build, or run `flutter doctor`?

Comment: Dear @TaufikNurRahmanda; I added their responses . . . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you do not accepted some android licenses. Just run:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

And accept `y` all licences.

Comment: This is the response: `A newer version of the Android SDK is required. To update, run: C:\Users\elyar\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager --update`. What should I do? I have `Android SDK Build-tools 29.0.3` installed.

Comment: Are you using a standalone Android-sdk or a AndroidStudio Android-sdk? Double check if you are using the right sdk. If you are using the right sdk, consider this link for solving your issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31116

Comment: I'm using an AndroidStudio Android-sdk . . .